# Left Outer Join in mongoose for multiple fields form a collection with multiple collection (Aggregate & lookups)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongoose aggregate.
How do I achieve left outer join for multiple fields using a single aggregate function

Collection1

```
{
 c1_field1,
 c1_field2,
 c1_field3
}
```

Collection2

```
{
 c2_field1(refs Collection1 c1_field1),
 c2_field2,
 c2_field3
}
```

Collection3

```
{
 c3_field1(refs Collection1 c1_field2),
 c3_field2,
 c3_field3
}
```

Help me to achieve output something like following schema

```
{
 collection2_with_ref:[{
               c2_field1,
               c2_field2,
               c2_field3
               },..],
 collection3_with_ref:[{
               c3_field1,
               c3_field2,
               c3_field3
               },..],
 c1_field3
}
```

Thank you...
I really want to know either the above mentioned can be achieved or not

Comment: In your o/p where did `c1_field2` go ? Is that a typo ?

Comment: Thank u I will update it

Comment: Hi , Is it working or still having issues ? If it is can you please accept this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it but in general you can do this using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) :

```
db.Collection1.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Collection2",
         localField: "c1_field1",
         foreignField: "c2_field1",
         as: "collection2_with_ref"
       }
  },{
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "Collection3",
         localField: "c1_field2",
         foreignField: "c3_field1",
         as: "collection3_with_ref"
       }
  }
])
```

This would add two new arrays to existing documents, if you wanted to remove  `c1_field1, c1_field2` use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) to exclude those fields, or you can specify respective field name in `$lookup`'s `as` that way they'll be replaced with `$lookup`'s result arrays.